# We should make [off-topic] synonymous with [scope]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms, meta

On our meta site, there are two different tags [off-topic](/questions/tagged/off-topic) and [scope](/questions/tagged/scope). But actually [off-topic](/questions/tagged/off-topic) is the synonyms under [scope](/questions/tagged/scope).

Refer to [MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/scope/synonyms):

[image: screen-shot]

Also done at [U & L](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3723/66803).

Comment: suggested to [post](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/25726055#25726055) here

Comment: Seems reasonable to me!